# remake user home directory

Tags: suse, sles

I can't seem to (re)make a home directory.  A script partially removed the account but it's not quite dead yet. I should probably just finish killing the account and remake it but in the meantime I'd like to figure out what's going on here. How do I do the needful to recreate this user home directory?

```
gsamsa@kafka:/> cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="15-SP3"
VERSION_ID="15.3"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP3"
ID="sles"
ID_LIKE="suse"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:15:sp3"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://documentation.suse.com/"

gsamsa@kafka:/> id
uid=1000(gsamsa) gid=100(users) groups=100(users)

gsamsa@kafka:/> echo $HOME
/home/gsamsa

gsamsa@kafka:/> ls -la /home
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   0 Jan 24 17:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 202 Jan 22 16:51 ..

gsamsa@kafka:/> cd
-bash: cd: /home/gsamsa: No such file or directory

gsamsa@kafka:/> mkdir $HOME
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/gsamsa’: Permission denied

gsamsa@kafka:/> sudo mkdir $HOME
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/gsamsa’: Permission denied

gsamsa@kafka:/> sudo mkhomedir_helper $HOME
gsamsa@kafka:/> echo $?
8

gsamsa@kafka:/> sudo useradd -m -d $HOME $( whoami )
useradd: user 'gsamsa' already exists

gsamsa@kafka:/> cd
-bash: cd: /home/gsamsa: No such file or directory

gsamsa@kafka:/> grep $( whoami ) /etc/passwd
gsamsa:1000:100:gsamsa:/home/gsamsa:/bin/bash

gsamsa@kafka:/>
```

Update1: turns out trying to create other accounts also ends up with the same "can't create directory /home/username" problem.

Update2: Not read-only. I was able to create files, just not directories.

```
kafka:~ # mount | grep /home
/dev/sda2 on /home type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=264,subvol=/@/home)
auto.home on /home type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=29,pgrp=20218,timeout=43200,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect,pipe_ino=183332)
/dev/sda2 on /home type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=264,subvol=/@/home)

kafka:~ # touch /home/foo
kafka:~ # mkdir /home/gsamsa
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/gsamsa’: File exists

kafka:~ # ls -la /home /home/foo
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18 Jan 24 18:02 /home
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  0 Jan 24 18:02 /home/foo
```

Update 3: The directory showed up sometime after writing *Update 2* but before I hit "Save edits."  And I'm able to create other users. I had logged out of the gsamsa account which must of released some sort of deadlock. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
gsamsa@kafka:/> sudo mkdir $HOME
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/gsamsa’: Permission denied
```

Most often happens then the /home is mounted on a read-only drive. A network one or live-CD as most common examples.

Comment: ro filesystem gives: `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/gsamsa’: Read-only file system`